# why pseudo class selector select all first children of it's child?

Tags: html, css

So I want to get a table just like the picture down below:

[image]

I used first-child and last-child selectors but they seem like they select all the first  and last elements IDK why, here's what I got:

[image]

here's what I've tried:

```css
<style>
    table {
        border: 1px solid #c4dcf3;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table :first-child, table :last-child {
        background-color: green;
    }

    table tbody:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

```html
   <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>OrderID</th>
            <th>Order Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>$1,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>1001</td>
            <td>$700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CA</td>
            <td>1002</td>
            <td>$2,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CA</td>
            <td>1003</td>
            <td>$1,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Because that is what you select. All `:first-child` and `:last-child` inside `table`. Maybe you want to add `td:first-child` to selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) have to be placed on the child-elements. Since you threw it on tables, it looked for the first and last table in a set of table, which probably don't exist.

You can also target `thead` and `tfoot` for your desired styling, which might be more appropriate.

Same principle applies to the alternating highlighting. [`table > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

I added a working snippet.

```css
<style>
        table {
            border: 1px solid #c4dcf3;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        thead,
        tfoot {
            background-color: green;
        }

        table > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>OrderID</th>
                <th>Order Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>$1,300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1001</td>
                <td>$700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1002</td>
                <td>$2,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1003</td>
                <td>$1,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>$5,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't target 1st / last child when you can simply target `thead` and `tfoot`

Also your code doesn't work because it should be:

```
table>*:first-child ,
table>*:last-child {
    background-color: green;
}
```

without `space`

Comment: Fixed selectors for case when first/last child is used as I provided wrong code at first

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply color on tr and make changes according to parent as you are using `thead, tbody, tfoot`. Your css not apply properly because you are using table tag there. table has 3 child `thead, tbody, tfoot` and each have their separate tr tags as first child and last child.

```css
<style>
        table {
            border: 1px solid #c4dcf3;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        thead tr,  tfoot tr{
            background-color: green;
        }
        tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>OrderID</th>
                <th>Order Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>$1,300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1001</td>
                <td>$700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1002</td>
                <td>$2,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1003</td>
                <td>$1,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>$5,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
        table {
            border: 1px solid #c4dcf3;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        thead,
        tfoot {
            background-color: #4e81e7;
        }

        
        tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>OrderID</th>
                <th>Order Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>$1,300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>USA</td>
                <td>1001</td>
                <td>$700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1002</td>
                <td>$2,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CA</td>
                <td>1003</td>
                <td>$1,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>$5,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```